# Android: Prevent SQL Errors displayed in log

Tags: android, database, exception

when I execute an invalid sql statement I get a error trance and a sql error. My error trace is obfuscated. But the sql error text is showing the complete sql statement. I dont want the user to see my db internals. Is it someho possible to disable this messages?

thanks
Euribor

Comment: yes ... you have to fix invalid statments

Comment: Why are you displaying internal exception trace to your user in the first place?

Comment: Sure, I fixed invalid statements. But nobody can say that all errors are gone forever.
And I do not display exceptions to the users. But they are present on the system.